# How to use curl with the MediaWiki API for register

Tags: mediawiki

I want to use mediawiki api to register user, i want to use curl to for  api calls, I tried with

```
function RegisterCurl()
{
    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    //$url = 'http://localhost/WC/gccfwiki/api.php';
    $myvar1 = "createaccount"; 
    $myvar2 = "http://localhost/WC/gccfwiki/";
    $myvar3 = $this->GetToken;
    // $remove = '+\\';
    // $myvar3 = str_replace($remove,"",$myvar3);
    $myvar4 = "Bob"; 
    $myvar5 = "ExamplePassword";
    $myvar6 = "ExamplePassword";
    $myvar7 = "midaj@gmail.com";
    $myvar8 = "Robert20Example";


    $myvars = 'action=' . $myvar1 . '&createreturnurl=' . $myvar2 . '&createtoken=' . $myvar3 . '&username=' . $myvar4. '&password=' . $myvar5 . '&retype=' . $myvar6 . '&email=' . $myvar7 . '&realname=' . $myvar8;

    $url = 'http://localhost/WC/gccfwiki/api.php';


    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 25);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($output);
    die();
    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

public function GetToken()
{
    $url = 'http://localhost/WC/gccfwiki/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=tokens&type=csrf|createaccount';
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);      
    $out=json_decode($output);print_r($out);die();
    $token = $out->query->tokens->createaccounttoken;
    return $token;
}
```

i got the response
{
    "error": {
        "code": "badtoken",
        "info": "Invalid CSRF token.",
        "*": "See http://localhost/WC/gccfwiki/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at <https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
    }
}

is there any solution.. how i solve it???

Comment: Are you wedded to the idea of using Curl directly? Because you could use the `addwiki/mediawiki-api` library instead, and this would be a lot simpler! :-)

Comment: i need to call curl from a different project to wiki...

Comment: Yes, but in that project you could do e.g. `$userCreator()->create('User name', 'pwd123');` and all the complexity would be handled for you by https://github.com/addwiki/mediawiki-api

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is "don't" (you are setting yourself up for a lot of pain by using hand-crafted curl queries instead of one of the existing [client libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#PHP)), but if you really insist, use the cookiefile/cookiejar curl options to preserve the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a token from the wiki first with a call like https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&type=createaccount, see also https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Account_creation

It depends a bit on which mediawiki version you are working with though.

Comment: i got a token in the first call, in the above  code  i mentioned gettoken(), and i passed it into the next curl, but it showing invalid csrf token

Comment: if GetToken is a function, shouldn't you call it as $this->getToken() [aka with parentheses?]